# How to modify a string array and save it to use for a listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button addcar;

String[]foods={"carone","cartwo","carthree"};


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){             <----- Here is where I thought I could get the updated array to be added to the listview.             
        String [] foods = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("foods");

        ListAdapter myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,foods);
        ListView mylistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mylistview.setAdapter(myadapter);

    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addcar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    addcar.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    Intent myintent = new Intent("com.example.husse.profilesalgortihm.Main2Activity");
                startActivity(myintent);
                }
            }
    );

  ListAdapter myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,foods);
 ListView mylistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    mylistview.setAdapter(myadapter);
   mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(
           new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   if (id == 0) {
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, foods[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   }
               }
           }
   );
}
}
```

My Second activity

```
    public class Main2Activity extends MainActivity   {
    public int number = 0;
    public EditText Model;
    public  EditText Body;
    public  EditText color;
    public String M; 
    public String B;
    public String C;
    private final String tag = "Main2activity";
    private Button add;
    Car_information[] cars = new Car_information[10];



     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   Model = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
   Body = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
   color = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
   add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
   M  =  Model.getText().toString();
    B = Body.getText().toString();
    C = color.getText().toString();
     // may run into issues with the final
    add.setOnClickListener(
       new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {  <--- Here is where I tried to save the information about the car but for the listview purpose I only wanted the name to be added to the Listview in the previous activity.


               cars[number] = new Car_information();

               cars[number].Model = M;
               cars[number].Body = B;
               cars[number].Color = C;
               foods[number]= M;<----- Updating the array with the name the of the vehicle the user put in
               number ++;

                    Intent intent = new      
                  Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);        
               intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
               startActivity(intent);

           }
       }
        );

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) { <----- where I tried to save the new updated array to be used in the listview, so the user could see the new listview when the user goes back to the firstactivity.
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
outState.putStringArray("foods",foods);
}
```

What I am trying to do is when the user goes to the second activity he/she will enter in the information about his/her vehicle, but when they click the add button it will take them back to the previous activity and it will save the name of the car that they entered, and display it on the listview. But the list isn't being updated when they go back to the firstactivity.

Comment: Where is foods defined in Main2Activity?

Comment: Are you trying to have a fixed size array? Or you wanna be flexible to add and delete item in the list?

Comment: Flexible @SalvatoryBaya

Comment: I am  inheriting from the first so the same string array in the first activity @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can use [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) function to implement your task.

Example: You are in Activity1 and want to get data from Activity2.

In Activity1, call intent to start Activity2 with specific request

```
static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code
...
private void pickContact() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    pickContactIntent.putExtra(...) <-- put some data to send to Activity2
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}
```

then override `onActivityResult` like

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // get data sent from Activity2 via data parameter
        }
    }
}
```

In Activity2, when you're done with process, send data back to Activity1 by flow

[setResult (int resultCode, Intent data)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)) > finish()

this data will send to `onActivityResult` above

Hope it help !